# Is there anything that a regular user can do to help remove fake websites?

Tags: malware, phishing, websites

I'm talking about domains like `msn.org` and `stackoveflow.com` that impersonate major websites and serve up malicious ads such as the "critical alert from Microsoft" ad.

I've tried reporting these ads to the companies before but they seem to just ignore my emails and I've tried reporting them to their web and domain host but they either say that it's not their problem or that the websites aren't malicious (???).

I've also tried reporting them through [Google's spam report form](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/spamreportform?hl=en) and [malicious software form](https://safebrowsing.google.com/safebrowsing/report_badware/) but Chrome still doesn't block them as being unsafe websites, so I'm not sure that they even read the reports.

Is there anything else that can be done?

Answer (score 1):

I think you've exhausted most possible solutions. What I suggest though, it's using adblockers on your preferred web browser so you won't encounter these ads anymore, but this still doesn't solve the actual issue.