# Anything I can do to combat malicious domains?

Tags: malware, virus, dns-domain

On Facebook, malware is currently trying to spread itself using the domain `googlediver (dot) com`, one sample of a malicious url is `https://googlediver (dot) com/list-of-traveling-staff` , and I believe that domain is used exclusively to spread malware.

Is there anything I can do to combat it? On ICANN lookup, I see

```
Registrar Information

    Name: GMO Internet Group, Inc. d/b/a Onamae.com
    IANA ID: 49
    Abuse contact email: abuse@gmo.jp
    Abuse contact phone: tel:+81.337709199
```

Is it perhaps worthwhile to e-mail or call that number to complain?

Suggestions?

Comment: Related: [Is there anything that a regular user can do to help remove fake websites?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/179130/56961)

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. You can report this domain to the likes of Google, Bing, Firefox, McAffee, other anti-virus providers as well as reporting it to the abuse email.

Reporting it to the abuse email will attempt to have the provider take down the page. From experience this almost never happens. Depending on who the provider is they will pass on your contact information to the person who purchased the domain and tell them you made a complaint - some providers explicitly tell you that they will do this.

The purpose of reporting it to Google, Microsoft, Firefox, etc is to have that warning page pop up when any user tries to access the site - you can still click that you accept the risk, but the idea is most people will nope out at that point.

How much weight any of these place on a single report from a random person is where you may fall down. I assume you don't have any official capacity you are acting in when making the reports. Even reports from law enforcement are not always acted on.

Ultimately if you are going to report them include as much **SPECIFIC** information in the report as possible. In your original post you said "I believe that domain is used exclusively to spread malware". If that is all you have to go on, you will not get very far.

I have worked in trying to combat scams and in my experience there is very little that can be done realistically. These people will easily register multiple domains all hosting the same thing (you can look through the associated site on the TLS certificate to see the ones that use the same certificate but there will be others) so having one taken down is a minor inconvenience to them. I can rant for hours about scams and the lack of resources worldwide being put into combating them, but we will go off topic very quickly.